# SQL Query Month over Month By System

Tags: sql-server

I'm setting up a report for system outages. The report must total the system outages by system for every month of the year, even if there are no outages, I still want a 0.

Here is a somewhat working query:

```
with Months as (
    select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate()) - n, 0) MonthDate
    from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11))dt(n))
SELECT  
    m.MonthDate,
    C.Name,
    Count(*) as 'Count'
from 
    Months m 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Incident I
        on (m.MonthDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,i.CreatedDateTime),0))
    Inner JOIN CI C on C.RecId = I.SystemName_Valid
WHERE   
    I.CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(MONTH,-11,GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY    
    m.MonthDate, C.Name
```

The results shows only the dates where there are system outages.

I expect the output to be like the following

```
MonthDate   Name     Count
1/1/2019    System1    0
1/1/2019    System2    0
1/1/2019    System3    0
1/1/2019    System4    0
2/1/2019    System1    0
2/1/2019    System2    0
2/1/2019    System3    0
2/1/2019    System4    1
3/1/2019    System1    1
3/1/2019    System2    0
3/1/2019    System3    0
3/1/2019    System4    0
4/1/2019    System1    0
4/1/2019    System2    0
4/1/2019    System3    0
4/1/2019    System4    0
```

The data set being returned though is

```
MonthDate   Name     Count
2/1/2019    System4    1
3/1/2019    System1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `FROM` clause to:

```
from 
    Months m 
    CROSS JOIN dbo.CI -- you want to have a row per month per system
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Incident I -- this needs to be *outer* so that combos
                                   -- without a match are still included
      ON (m.MonthDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,i.CreatedDateTime),0))
      AND C.RecId = I.SystemName_Valid
      AND I.CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(MONTH,-11,GETDATE()) -- this is redundant
```

When you put an *optional* table into either an INNER / ON clause or the WHERE clause, you turn an outer join (give me all the months and include **any** incident rows when we find one that matches) into an inner join (give me **only** months that have matching incidents).

I'd also change this:

```
on (m.MonthDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,i.CreatedDateTime),0))
```

To this:

```
ON i.CreatedDateTime >= m.MonthDate
AND i.CreatedDateTime < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m.MonthDate)
```

This will allow the use of an existing (or future) index that has `CreatedDateTime` in the key, which may or may not be more useful depending on how much data is in the incidents table. Your current expression will force a scan of the entire table because it will have to evaluate the output for every single row.

Comment: Aaron, I have tried your suggestion however the result is identical. I think the problem is because the Incident table only references the system when it is an outage.

Comment: How is that possible? If `dbo.CI` has 4 rows, this query should return 48 rows, even if `dbo.Incident` is completely empty. My guess is you still have a clause somewhere that affects the incidents table and forces the outer join to become an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Using what Aaron has posted, I modified the query, and I got it working with the following:

```
with Months as (
    select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate()) - n, 0) MonthDate
    from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11))dt(n))
SELECT  
    m.MonthDate,
    CI.Name,
    (Select 
        count(*) 
    from 
        Incident I 
    where 
        i.SystemOutageIssue = 1 and I.CreatedDateTime >= m.MonthDate and 
        I.CreatedDateTime < DateAdd(day,1,EOMONTH(m.MonthDate)) and
        I.SystemName = CI.Name) as 'Count'
from 
    Months m 
    Cross JOIN CI
GROUP BY    
    m.MonthDate, CI.Name
```

Thanks Aaron for your help, I haven't used Cross Join before, not like this anyway.

Comment: This may "work" but it's a far less efficient way to do it than the modifications I posted (my suggestion was incomplete because you've added clauses in your answer, like `SystemOutageIssue` and `SystemName`, that weren't in your question at the time). But you really should compare the execution plans, especially if you have an adequate index to support a date range seek on incidents.